# javascript content changes by itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache, tomcat

This problem sometimes happens.

It doesn't happen in the same part.

Below is an example.

```
// original js
var $btn = $(this).find('a');    << no problem

// change source js
var $btn = $(this).find('a#);    << Uncaught SuntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

or

```
// original js
$("#text.select.year span").text("");   << select 

// change source js
$("#text.seawsq.year span").text("");   << seawsq?
```

This phenomenon occurs repeatedly. Elsewhere ...

it happen is resolved ctrl+f5(ie) and ctrl+shift+r(chrome)

But i would like to know the cause.

What can happen when this happens? browser problem? and apache?

I used IE 11 and Chrome 77 and jquery 1.12.4

Comment: server problem for sure - what hardware is the server running on

Comment: server is linux system. apache 2.4 and tomcat 8.5 but the same happens with localhost

Comment: `linux system` - that's an operating system, not hardware

Comment: You actually do have a syntax error in the second line of code, you are missing a '

Comment: @Bravo `uname -a  >> Linux WAS1 2.6.32-696.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 21 00:53:17 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`   is this right??

Comment: yep, that's still a lot of software no hardware info ... but, I don't think the hardware is a problem now